# Custom Scrolling on a div

Tags: jquery, html, custom-scrolling

I have this piece of code in my mvc view where htmlcollection is a collection of many tables containing 4 rows each. Each table has a height of 40 px.

```
         var scrollWindow = $('<div>', {
                id: "scroll-window",
                html: htmlCollection
            });

        <style>
           #scroll-window {
           height: 655px;
           width: inherit;
           overflow-y: auto;
           }
          </style>

         $('#divCateringPX').append(scrollWindow);
```

I also have a button in my view on clicking which I want to scroll down a multiple of 40 px in divCateringPX. This question looks simple, but I am new to jquery and stuck. Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Here on **StackOverflow**, besides upvoting we also _accept_ answers if they prove to be actual solutions to the problem posted.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is attach the button a click event, which calls back to a function which scrolls inside the div, like so:

```
var m=1,
    pos;

$("#button").click(function(){

    pos = $("#divCateringPX").scrollTop();

    $("#divCateringPX").animate({
        scrollTop: pos + 40*m
    }, 1500);

});
```

1500 is the animation duration expressed in **miliseconds**.
The above code will scroll 40px down per click. If you want to scroll down a number of pixels equal to a multiple of 40, just change the `m` variable to your desired multiple.

Oh, and by the way, you should set the `scrollTop` property not just to 40px, but to the **initial** scrolling position **plus** 40px. If you hadn't done this, it would have only worked the first time. After that, it would have set the `scrollTop` property to 40 everytime, which did nothing at all. I had edited my code.